# RoboVM: App not loading on iPhone

Tags: ipa, robovm

To begin, the app is working on the iPhone simulators. The problem is the difficulty in creating the signing identity, cert, ect. Here are the steps I am taking and I would be grateful if someone could point out something I am doing in error!

Here is my setup for my Certificates, Identifiers, & Profiles:

**Certificate-**
[image]
**App ID-**
[image]
**Provisioning Profile-**
[image]

Also, here are other important screenshots for this application-

[image]

I am not necessarily getting any errors in any part of this process, but whenever I move the created IPA file over from iTunes onto the phone (iPhone6), it begins to load and initialize before it stops and disappears. Thanks for the help!

EDIT: My robovm configuration is in the Project build.gradle file, under section:

```
project(":ios"){
```

Comment: seem that your are confusing Distribution with Development signIdentity

Comment: I have tried using "iPhone Developer: ###" in my robovm configuration as well though.

Comment: ok, I had the same problem some day ago. Why you are not using the robovm menu (play button) and try to deploy the app directly from him?

Comment: I am using the RoboVM fork from mobidevelop as I didn't get onboard soon enough to get a free license key of the original. I don't believe that there is a program associated with the fork, is there? I thought it was all done through android studio. Correct me if I am wrong though!

Comment: I'm using robovm fork http://robovm.mobidevelop.com/ and the latest android studio and in my configuration I can select ROBOVM edit it and deploy it! For sure, it works!

Comment: Wow okay, I think I may have missed something here! Would you walk me through what I need to do? Is it in the "Run/Debug Configurations" window? The same one that you create an emulator in? Thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135190/discussion-between-saret-and-michael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the reason for this. Everything was fine except for in the robovm.properties file. I had:

```
app.id=com.on*******
```

and what I needed was

```
app.id=com.on*******.*
```

The wildcard at the end was necessary, and I am sure the actual name would work as well. Thanks for the help Saret

Answer (score 0):

Select your attached device and the right signing identity and provisioning profile. Also be sure that your device is enabled in the apple developer console with your certificate.

[image]

Comment: When I manually select it, it looks like it gets up to 40% before stopping: [ERROR] Couldn't start application
org.robovm.libimobiledevice.LibIMobileDeviceException: ApplicationVerificationFailed
 at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher$1.error(AppLauncher.java:1001)
 at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.Callbacks.callInstproxyCallback(Callbacks.java:64)
...
[INFO] [ 20%] InspectingPackage
[INFO] [ 20%] TakingInstallLock
[INFO] [ 30%] PreflightingApplication
[INFO] [ 30%] InstallingEmbeddedProfile
[INFO] [ 40%] VerifyingApplication

Comment: When I let it Auto select the Signing Identity and Provisioning profile I get this error: [ERROR] Couldn't compile app java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No provisioning profile found matching signing identity 'iPhone Developer: M**********(U********C)' and app bundle ID 'com.on**********

Comment: @Michael anything new about this?